# Drive not appearing after reboot

Tags: hard-drive, reboot, drive

I'm using Ubuntu desktop but it's primarily used as a server. I have data being stored on external drives that the server needs to access, but after rebooting, the drive doesn't appear through terminal commands. For example, if I reboot I get this when looking for the drive:

```
$ cd /media/user && ls
$
```

Nothing gets returned when looking for where the drive should be. However, if I open up the GUI file explorer and go to the drive, it's there, and after opening up the drive's folder, I can run the same command again:

```
$ cd /media/user && ls
data1
$
```

And it's there and everything works fine after that. How can I have it automatically show up there on startup without having to use the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if it is mounted (and with which options) with `mount` (when the disk IS mounted) see `man mount`), find its UUID with `sudo blkid -o export` (will show all devices) (see `man blkid`), and arrange for it to be mounted by editing `/etc/fstab` (see `man fstab`). You should look at the `auto` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I also found `gnome-disks` has an easy GUI method for this but  I used your method and worked fine.